# Get authenticated user from Vertex AI notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vertex

is there any way to get the user name who is currently in the Vertex AI Notebook?

For example in Vertex AI Notebok if I do this:

```
$ curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/email" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

I get: notebook-sa@tp.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Or if I do this using Python:

```
import os
user = os.environ.get("USER")
print(f"USER = {user}")
```

I get: USER = jupyter

So I expect to get something like this: my_gcp_user@my_domain.com

Comment: Your first example gets the principal for Vertex AI. Your second example gets the principal for the operating system. You are asking different authentication systems.

Comment: Yes you right. I only want to find the way to get `my_gcp_user@my_domain.com` from Vertex AI Notebook.